# Vector 3 does only change x on first run in a for loop but not next time

Tags: c#, loops, unity-game-engine, vector

I have this code here and down the line I'm spawning an object in a loop and in my heartGameobjectTempVec3 to dox -- .5316515f each time it loops.

**Problems**

It does change the valuable on the first time it runs the for loop. But does not change the x next time, but it does spawn the object again, now inside the just spawned object.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class GameUIManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float heartGameobjectX;
    public float heartGameobjectY;
    public float heartGameobjectZ;
    public int scoreCount;
    public int lives;
    public int liveCount;
    public int dogsEscaped;
    public GameObject[] spawnebleObjects;
    public GameObject heartGameobject;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        Vector3 heartGameobjectTempVec3 = new Vector3(heartGameobjectX, heartGameobjectY, heartGameobjectZ);
        Instantiate(heartGameobject, heartGameobjectTempVec3, transform.rotation);
        liveCount--;
        for (int i = 1; i <= liveCount; i++)
        {
            heartGameobjectTempVec3[0] = -.5316515f;
                Instantiate(heartGameobject, heartGameobjectTempVec3, transform.rotation);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Instantiate returns a clone of the original object hearGameObject, do you need to be storing this anywhere? I don't know unity, but I would assume you have to tell unity to show the object or something.

Comment: You're using `Start` and not `Update`. `Start` will run once. Also, as @Evgenii said, you're setting the value directly, and not incrementing or decrementing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not shure, but you probably should do -=(or +=) there.

```
heartGameobjectTempVec3[0] -= -.5316515f;
```

Comment: Im soo thankfull for your help all of you guys you made me come out with a way maby not to bueatifull but it works fine for me :)

Comment: Love you all <3

Comment: is there some how i close this topic cause i got what i needed .

Comment: @CubeCrafter360 You can mark this answer as the correct answer and that will resolve the question.